# Rails Refactoring: More efficient ActiveRecord Queries and Condition Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, coding-style, refactoring

In a model I am trying to return a conditional ActiveRecord result set.  If the author has written books, return those.  If the author hasn't written any books, return articles.  This works:

```
def writings  
  Books.where(author_id: 1).present? ? Books.where(author_id: 1)  : Articles.where(author_id: 2)  
end
```

How can this be improved
1.  When checking conditions and setting values, i.e not executing the `Books.where` query twice?
2.  From a performance standpoint

I'm working on improving my efficiency and style and often use either [Style Guide bbatsov](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) or the [addition](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) method combined with a double pipe:

```
def writings
  Books.where(author_id: 1).presence || Articles.where(author_id: 2)
end
```

---

From the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence

> `presence() public`
>
> Returns the receiver if it’s present otherwise returns `nil`.

Some examples:

```
true.presence # => true
1.presence # => 1
false.presence # => nil
[].presence # => nil
''.presence # => nil
User.where(id: -1).presence # => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing `counter_cache` on both Book and Article models.

```
# class Book
belongs_to :author, counter_cache: true

# class Article
belongs_to :author, counter_cache: true
```

Read more about counter caching [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).

Then you can inspect the value of `books_count` before running any queries.

```
# class Author
# assumes has_many :books
# and     has_many :articles
def writings
  if books_count.nonzero?
    books
  else
    articles
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you are now always doing 2 queries. 1 - to get present?, second to get either books or Articles.

You can improve by changing code so that is selects books and if there are none, then returns articles.

```
def writings  
  books = Books.where(author_id: 1) 
  if books.size > 0 
    books
  else
    Articles.where(author_id: 2)  
  end
end
```